# Array merge and Str_replace in php

Tags: php, str-replace, array-merge

In my php code each iteration give the result as below

```
first iteration:
Array 
([ZN1874] => (12 >  5)
[ZN101]   => (20 >  5)
)

second iteration:
Array 
(
[ZN1874] => (12 >  3)
[ZN101]  => (20 >  3)
)
```

Here I want to combine the arrays with the index value and have to add a condition (or a string) in merging.
for example my final output should has to come as

```
Array 
([ZN1874] => (12 >  5) AND (12 >  3)
[ZN101]   => (20 >  5  AND 20 >  3)
)
```

What are the possibilities?

Comment: The limit of posibilities how to do what you want is only your imagination. This is offtopic question asking for tutorial

Comment: Try `if(isset($newArray[$key])) $newArray[$key] .= ' AND '.$item['something'];`  But no one can answer this without the code you use for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: I am assuming you don't want to override the existing array.If you want to override then instead of using new array variable, you can put it in old `$arr` or `$arr1` also.

```
$arr = array("ZN1874" => "(12 >  5)", "ZN101"   => "(20 >  5)");
$arr1  = Array ("ZN1874" => "(12 >  3)", "ZN101"   => "(20 >  3)");
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1  as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists($key,$arr)){
        $newArr[$key] = $arr[$key]." and ".$val;
    }
    else {
       $newArr[$key] = $arr[$key]." and ".$val;
    }
}

print_r($newArr); //Output Array ( [ZN1874] => (12 > 5) and (12 > 3) [ZN101] => (20 > 5) and (20 > 3) )
```

Comment: Why do you check `array_key_exists()` as both branches of code are the same?

Comment: @NigelRen, I am not sure always both the array will contain all the key. If not, then new array variable will miss some key.